# How to auto login in angularjs application with url

Tags: angularjs, passport.js

Can anyone say me how to auto login with angularjs 1.x .I will be sending the email with url and when they click on that url it should autoredirect to home page.

The url will be having email and encrypted password:

http://localhost:8080/login/amg1.2.3@outlook.com/$2a$08$cZPWmzta7Gn9Mj14r7zGWeMPKNKkkg8JS3gWNL2fQaFuBwrhgKQC

Clicking on this url should redirect me to home page without any login page.
I am using passport for login functionality.

can you explain me how,iam using passport with form post like this

```
app.get('/login/:email/:pwd', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.params.email);
  console.log(req.params.pwd);
  var request = require('request');
  request.post({
    headers: {'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    url:     'http://localhost:8080/login/',
    form:    { email: req.params.email,password:req.params.pwd }
  }, function(error, response, body){
    console.log(error);  
    console.log(body);
    console.log(response);
  });
});
```

Please check the gist how I am doing and tell me how can i improve the code gist.github.com/agupta330/0fb55b50eecf4b1305ebfe15869b295d

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with angular, because it is serverside.

You should not use the encryted password, because your link will never expire. It is better to generate a random key and store it in your database like you do it with sessions ids.

If the user clicks on the link an the key is valid and not expires, you generate a new session and send the session cookie together with the redict to your angular page to the user.

For the angular page you not have to change anything, because it seems like the user is loggedin like normal (with the session in the cookie)

Comment: can you explain me how,iam using passport from this url

Comment: If you get the url you look in your db from witch user the token is and if it is not expired. If you dont find the token it is invalid and you redict to the login page. If it is valid you say passport it should login the user (without password). Passport will then automaticly create a new session, store it and send the session cookie.

Comment: yah iam taking email ferom the above url to find the user info but its not happening auto login is not happening

Comment: Julian has explained quite exactly what to do. It will take some hours to implement it, so how can it be that you tell us it's not working?

Comment: Hello Matt I am doing form post with url encoded to post the form so that passport post function can happen

Comment: app.get('/login/:email/:pwd', function(req, res) {
            var request = require('request');
            request.post({
              headers: {'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
              url:     'http://localhost:8080/login/',
              form:    { email: req.params.email,password:req.params.pwd }
            }, function(error, response, body){
              console.log(error);  
              console.log(body);
            
            });
        });

Comment: Please check the gist how I am doing and tell me how can i improve the code https://gist.github.com/agupta330/0fb55b50eecf4b1305ebfe15869b295d